# Load 1 list image from MySQL database into list JSP Page

Tags: java, jquery, html, mysql, jsp

i have a problem with my jsp page.
Firstly i create a database have table image have some properties imageID, imageTitle, imageURL, imageStyle
Continue i create a new jsp page
This is code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            try {
            String _URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/slider";
            String _USER = "root";
            String _PASS = "password";
            java.sql.Connection connection = null;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_URL, _USER, _PASS);
            //if(!connection.isClosed())
                 //out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
            //connection.close();

            int img_id = 1;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            String strslide = "";
            strslide += "<div class=\"panel\">";

            strslide += "<div class=\"container\"><div class=\"wt-rotator\">";
            strslide +="<a href=\"#\"></a>";
            strslide += "<div class=\"desc\"></div><div class=\"preloader\"></div><div class=\"c-panel\"><div class=\"buttons\">";
            strslide+="<div class=\"prev-btn\"></div>";
            strslide+="<div class=\"play-btn\"></div>";
            strslide+="<div class=\"next-btn\"></div>";

            strslide+="</div>";

            strslide +="<div class=\"thumbnails\">";
            strslide += "<ul>"; 
            try {
                pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from image where id = @id");
                pstmt.setInt(1, img_id);
                rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                if(rs.next()) {
                   // some code at here
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("Unable to connect to database"+ex);
        } 

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont know how to show image into page with jsp code , this code i write some ideal. I create connection into mysql, after that i select query to take some properties from table image . After i want give propeerties into my code to show image into page.

At here i have a css file, a js file, some picture at path images/...

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

First it is bad practice to do java code in jsp. You have to create separate class SliderDao and put all jdbc code there.

Creating PreparedStatement is not like:

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from image where id = @id");
```

It should be like

```
pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("select * from image where id = ?");
pstmt.setInt(1, img_id);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Read this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#create_ps

Comment: yes this is my first time i work with jsp . it's bad thanks you !

Comment: This tutorial seems good http://o7planning.org/en/10285/create-a-simple-java-web-application-using-servlet-jsp-and-jdbc. How to accept answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers